# C# LUIS Chatbot extract all intents from LuisResult

Tags: c#, json, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a chatbot that is connected with LUIS, I know although the dialog will only go into the one with the highest matching intent, however I would still want to display the scores of the rest of the intents, is there a way to do that?
I already have

```
[LuisModel("XXXX", "XXXX", Verbose = true)]
```

So far this is what I'm using:

```
    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {

        string allIntents = "";



        //Loop throught all intents found in JSON
        foreach (var foundIntent in result.Intents)
        {
            allIntents += ("Intent: " + foundIntent.Intent + "\n\n" + "Score: " + foundIntent.Score + "\n\n");
        }
        await context.PostAsync(allIntents);
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

And my JSON is like

```
{
  "query": "hey there",
  "topScoringIntent": {
  "intent": "None",
  "score": 0.17292054
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.17292054
    },
    {
      "intent": "intentSearch",
      "score": 0.122199811
    },
    {
      "intent": "fromIntent",
      "score": 0.0327471271
    },
    {
      "intent": "goWithIntent",
      "score": 0.010828237
    }
  ],
  "entities": []
}
```

However my bot will only return the none intent and its score. Is there a way of returning all of the intent inside a dialog?

**EDIT**: The answer somehow worked on a new project and I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the verbose flag to true in your LuisModelAttribute like so:

```
[LuisModel("e7a9c2d5-0b92-47d3-9d73-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"4941fa348c49494db1e8e8xxxxxxxxxx", Verbose = true)]
```

This is the code to get all the intents, which you can get your scores from

```
    [LuisIntent("greeting")]
    public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string allIntents = "";
        //Loop throught all intents found in JSON
        foreach (var foundIntent in result.Intents)
        {
            allIntents += ("Intent: " + foundIntent.Intent + "\n\n" + "Score: " + foundIntent.Score + "\n\n");
        }
        await context.PostAsync(allIntents);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

using this code I got this result:
[image]

Comment: I just set `verbose = true` but it is still the same

Comment: And I'm still only getting one intent, I've even stepped through the breakpoint and for result it says `Intent count = 1`